# MASM error: A2032 error Specifed size

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

This program is supposed to compare an array of five elements to the min and max values for each element in the array.  I'm not sure why that when I compare the array to the max array and min array I get this error

> 1>......\Users\ross\Desktop\chapter6HW.asm(97): error A2032:
>   invalid......\Users\ross\Desktop\chapter6HW.asm(99)r specified size

Here's my code. I have marked where the error is with `** **` .

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
str1 BYTE "Invalid",0
str2 BYTE "Valid", 0
str3 BYTE "The PIN under Validation is:",0
minArr BYTE 5,2,4,1,3
maxArr BYTE 9,5,8,4,6

arr1 BYTE 6,4,5,3,5
arr2 BYTE 1,4,5,3,5
arr3 BYTE 8,4,5,2,5
arr4 BYTE 5,4,9,2,6

.code
main PROC
call Clrscr

mov esi,OFFSET arr1
call Display
call Validate_PIN

cmp eax,0

je L1

mov edx,OFFSET str1
call WriteString
call Crlf

L1:
mov edx,OFFSET str2
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf

mov esi,OFFSET arr2

call Display
call Validate_PIN

cmp eax,0
je L2
mov edx,OFFSET str1
call WriteString
call Crlf

L2:
mov edx,OFFSET str2

call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf
mov esi,OFFSET arr3

call Display

call Validate_PIN

cmp eax,0

je l3

mov edx,OFFSET str1
call WriteString
call Crlf

L3:
mov edx,OFFSET str2
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf

mov esi,OFFSET arr4
call Display
call Validate_PIN

cmp eax,0
je L4
mov edx,OFFSET str1
call WriteString
call Crlf
L4:
mov edx,OFFSET str2
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf
exit 
main ENDP

Validate_PIN PROC
mov edi,0
mov ecx,5

L1:
**cmp [esi],minArr[edi]**
jb L2
**cmp [esi],maxArr[edi]**
ja L2
inc esi
inc edi
cmp edi,5
je L3
loop L1
L2:
mov eax,edi
inc eax
jmp L4
L3:
mov eax,0
L4:
ret
Validate_PIN ENDP

Display PROC
mov edx,OFFSET str3
call WriteString
mov ecx,5
L1:
mov eax,[esi]
call WriteDec
inc esi
loop L1
call Crlf
ret
Display ENDP

End main
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a memory operand with another memory operand like that. You'll have to use a register as an intermediary:

```
mov al,[esi]
cmp al,minArr[edi]
jb L2
cmp al,maxArr[edi]
```

---

Another potential issue is that your `Display` routine doesn't seem to preserve the original value of `esi`, which `Validate_PIN` relies on.

Comment: Why is that?  Is it because they are not the same size?

Comment: No. It's because in general you can't perform operations where both the source and destinations are memory operands. If you have a memory operand, then the other operand usually needs to be a register or an immediate.